# Why restore a single node of a cluster?

Tags: restore, cassandra

We were reviewing the restore documentation for Cassandra [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_snapshot_restore_t.html), and noted it made the following distinction between restoring a single node or an entire cluster:

> If restoring a single node, you must first shutdown the node. If restoring an entire cluster, you must shut down all nodes, restore the snapshot data, and then start all nodes again.

Under what circumstances would restoring a backup of a single node be desirable compared to spinning up a clean node and letting it gather its data the normal way from the other replicas?